# Navier-Stokes eqs. correspond to $F=m*a$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

I have the (typical) Navier--Stokes system for incompressible fluid:

$$div(u)=0$$
$$\rho(u_t+u\cdot\nabla u)=-\nabla p+div(\nu\nabla u)+\rho g$$

In a paper that I'm reading says that the term

$$u_t+u\cdot\nabla u$$

is an **acceleration**. I can understand that $u_t$ (the derivative of the velocity $u$ with respect to time) is in fact an acceleration, **but, why "$u_t+u\cdot\nabla u$" is also an acceleration?**

My second question is: **why the right side terms
$$-\nabla p+div(\nu\nabla u)+\rho g$$
represent the sum forze?**

Comment: It would be useful for you to look at the [Material Derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_derivative)

Comment: I find the integral formulations of conservation equations easier to understand than the differential formulations. You should find them in any good textbook on continuum mechanics and fluid dynamics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$u_t$ on its own is the rate of change of velocity *at a point*. Fluid is flowing past that point, so the bit of fluid that the velocity is referring to is constantly changing.  In order to apply $\vec F=m\vec a$, you need to think of a fluid parcel.  You want to consider the acceleration of, and the forces acting on, a little box of fluid, the boundaries of which move along with the flow. For example, if you have steady flow in a pipe, and the pipe diameter decreases, the fluid speeds up as it squeezes into the smaller pipe. Another way of saying that is that as a bit of fluid comes along, it accelerates.  However, $u_t$ is zero everywhere (it's steady flow). $u \cdot \nabla u$ is the part of the acceleration that the fluid experiences due to moving to a new location.

The terms on the right hand side are the forces: there's a pressure gradient force, a viscous force, and a gravitational force.